# Qt matchmaking Server

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking

I want to build a matchmaking globe server,so that players on the internet can connect to and find an opponent, every player is represented by a `QTcpSocket` on the server.

My question is how to make the two socket talk to each other without using the glob server as a middle man? Is that even possible?

Do I need to create a server on one of them and give the other one its address?

If yes, what about NAT can I use the host number in the TCP protocol - I don't wanna use port forwarding.

Or is there any other approach in matchmaking that I don't know about.

Comment: You'll need the middleman at least at the beginning, so that the two players' computers can find each other.  After that, you might be able to use TCP hole-punching techniques to get the two player computers to talk to each other directly, or you might not (in which case they would need to fall back to communicating through your server).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching

Comment: In case hole punching does not work, make shure to check out the low-level network functions of your server OS, as most have some kind of "routing" functionality that speeds up networ-IO if you only route the traffic from one peer to another. Note: This means you can't use QTcpSocket on the server